# How can I filter the dates of this array by taking only the day?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My app uses Core Data and I added an attribute in CoreData Date.
Recovery values ​​as follows:

```
- (void)fetchedResults {
    // Core Data
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    // NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date == %@) AND (date <= %@)", [_meetingArray valueForKey:@"when"], [_meetingArray valueForKey:@"when"]];
    // NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"listingID != %@", [_meetingArray valueForKey:@"when"]];

    NSFetchRequest *execQuery =[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *descOggetto = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Meetings" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [execQuery setEntity:descOggetto];
    // [execQuery setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;

    _meetingArray = [context executeFetchRequest:execQuery error:&error];
    _results = [context executeFetchRequest:execQuery error:&error];

    NSError *saveError = nil;
    [context save:&saveError];
}
```

With the method **viewDidLoad** I create arrays and dictionaries and then dictate them:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self fetchedResults];

    _myArr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[_meetingArray valueForKey:@"when"]];
    _myDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:_myArr forKey:@"when"];

    _unsortedDays = _myDict[@"when"][0];
    _sortedDays = [_unsortedDays sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    NSLog(@"unsorted: %@, sorted: %@", _unsortedDays, _sortedDays);
    NSLog(@"sorted count: %ld", _sortedDays.count);

}
```

and comes out of this output:

```
2014-03-19 18:38:32.218 GroupData[8815:70b] unsorted: (
    "2014-03-19 16:00:33 +0000",
    "2014-03-20 17:00:33 +0000",
    "2014-03-21 14:00:33 +0000",
    "2014-03-17 14:00:33 +0000",
    "2014-03-18 15:00:33 +0000",
    "2014-03-20 17:45:56 +0000",
    "2014-03-20 17:45:56 +0000"
), sorted: (
    "2014-03-17 14:00:33 +0000",
    "2014-03-18 15:00:33 +0000",
    "2014-03-19 16:00:33 +0000",
    "2014-03-20 17:00:33 +0000",
    "2014-03-20 17:45:56 +0000",
    "2014-03-20 17:45:56 +0000",
    "2014-03-21 14:00:33 +0000"
)
2014-03-19 18:38:32.219 GroupData[8815:70b] sorted count: 7
```

**Now, how can I delete duplicate results?**

Comment: Your question title *"How can I filter the dates ... ?"* and the final question *"Now, how can I delete the results ... ?"* are completely different. - Please explain better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You're right, but I also have confusion about this. I think the best thing is "How can I delete the results the same".

Comment: I don't know what "How can I delete the results the same" means. Are you trying to remove duplicate dates?

Comment: You have to remove or create me another array with the results without duplicates

Comment: you can fetch distinct objects

NSSet *unique=[fetchedNamesDic valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfSets.name"];

Answer (score 0):

How about NSSet?

```
NSSet aSet = [NSSet setWithArray: _unsortedDays];
```

Now all the strings in the *unsortedDays* array will be the *aSet* object.

What you want the data back out of the set as an array?

```
_unsortedNoDupes = [aSet allObjects] ;
```

I hope this is what you are looking for?

Comment: NSSet I delete the duplicates

Comment: You said earlier that you wanted to delete the duplicates.

Comment: I need a method that i delete, hide, ect dates that have the same day

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to iterate through the dates, store the day portion in a set, and remove the date if it has been used.

This code will turn the day part of the date into a string and remove the item from the array if the day string has been encountered before.

```
NSMutableSet *usedDays = [NSMutableSet new];
for (int i=0; i<[_sortedDays count]; i++) {
    NSDate *date = _sortedDays[i];
    NSString *dateString = [date descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%Y-%m-%d" timeZone:nil locale:nil];

    if ([usedDays containsObject:dateString]) {
        // This day has already been used. Remove this date from the array.
        [_sortedDays removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        i--;
    } else {
        // This is a new day, mark it as having been used
        [usedDays addObject:dateString];
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that you might encounter problems if the dates are from different locales/timezones. In that case make sure they are normalized and that the description uses the same locale you used elsewhere in your code.

Comment: This might be fine, but I get an error here: descriptionWithCalendarFormat and here [_sortedDays removeObjectAtIndex: i];

Comment: Perhaps your _sortedDays is not mutable? The code compiles fine for me.